# How to fetch font awesome icon from JSON data in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, font-awesome

I have an array of json data. Using axios I am fetching data from API and I want to mapping with different json data. Everything is fetching properly. but font awesome icons are not fetching. Inside of that its fetching pure code in front end UI eg.(Spa). this is what I have tried. Please go throw my code.

I have tried several different ways of adding font awesome icons by using , , etc. I have tried many of the solutions suggested here, however I am unable to get any of it to produce icons.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  {amenitiesdata.map((amenities, index) => (
                                <div key={index} className="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                                    <p>{amenitiesUiMap[amenities].img + '' + amenitiesUiMap[amenities].name}</p>
                                </div>
                            ))}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './src/../../assets/css/homenavbarwithsearch.css';
import '../../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import NavBar from './navbar';
import Example from '../Components/datepicker';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../scripts/api';

class HomeNavBarwithSearch extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            propertyname: [],
            buildingtype: [],
            amenitiesdata: [],
            uiRoomType: {
                "SingleBedRoom": "Single Bed Room",
                "DoubleBedRoom": "Double Bed Room",
                "OneBHKApartment": "One BHK Apartment",
                "TwoBHKApartment": "Two BHK Apartment",
                "ThreeBHKApartment": "Three BHK Apartment",
            },

            amenitiesUiMap: {
                "AirConditioning": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fas fa-snowflake\"></i>",
                    "name": "Air Conditioning"
                },
                "AirportTransfer": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fa fa-plane\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>",
                    "name": "Airport Transfer"
                },
                "Balcony": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fas fa-dungeon\"></i>",
                    "name": "Balcony"
                },
                "Bathtub": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fa fa-bath\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>",
                    "name": "Bathtub"
                },
                "BusinessFriendly": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fa fa-handshake-o\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>",
                    "name": "Business Friendly"
                },
                "CarPark": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fa fa-car\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>",
                    "name": "Car Park"
                },
                "CoffeeMaker": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fa fa-coffee\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>",
                    "name": "Coffee Maker"
                },
                "DisableFriendly": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fas fa-wheelchair\"></i>",
                    "name": "Disable Friendly"
                },
                "FrontDesk": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fa fa-desktop\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>",
                    "name": "Front Desk"
                },
                "FullyFurnished": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fas fa-couch\"></i>",
                    "name": "Fully Furnished"
                },
                "Gym": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fas fa-dumbbell\"></i>",
                    "name": "Gym"
                },
                "Heating": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fas fa-water\"></i>",
                    "name": "Heater"
                },
                "Internet": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fa fa-wifi\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>",
                    "name": "WiFi"
                },
                "Kitchen": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fas fa-utensils\"></i>",
                    "name": "Kitchen"
                },
                "Nightclub": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fas fa-glass-cheers\"></i>",
                    "name": "Nightclub"
                },
                "NonSmoking": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fas fa-smoking-ban\"></i>",
                    "name": "Non Smoking"
                },
                "PetsAllowed": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fas fa-dog\"></i>",
                    "name": "Pets Allowed"
                },
                "PrivatePool": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fas fa-swimming-pool\"></i>",
                    "name": "Private Pool"
                },
                "Refrigerator": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fas fa-door-closed\"></i>",
                    "name": "Refrigerator"
                },
                "Restaurant": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fas fa-bread-slice\"></i>",
                    "name": "Restaurant"
                },
                "Sauna": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fas fa-hot-tub\"></i>",
                    "name": "Sauna"
                },
                "SemiFurnished": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fas fa-chair\"></i>",
                    "name": "Semi Furnished"
                },
                "Smoking": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fas fa-smoking\"></i>",
                    "name": "Smoking"
                },
                "SmokingArea": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fas fa-smoking\"></i>",
                    "name": "Smoking Area"
                },
                "Spa": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fas fa-spa\"></i>",
                    "name": "Spa"
                },
                "SwimmingPool": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fas fa-swimmer\"></i>",
                    "name": "Swimming Pool"
                },
                "TV": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fa fa-television\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>",
                    "name": "TV"
                },
                "Terrace": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fas fa-dungeon\"></i>",
                    "name": "Terrace"
                },
                "WashingMachine": {
                    "img": "<i className=\"fas fa-dumpster\"></i>",
                    "name": "Washing Machine"
                }
            }
        }
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        axios.all([
            axios.get(`/facility`),
            axios.get(`/meta/roomtypes?buildingtype=Hotel`),
            axios.get(`/facility`)
        ])
            .then(axios.spread((propertyname, buildingtype, amenitiesdata) => {
                console.log(propertyname.data[0].name, buildingtype.data);
                this.setState({
                    propertyname: propertyname.data[0].name,
                    buildingtype: buildingtype.data,
                    amenitiesdata: amenitiesdata.data[0].amenities
                });
            }))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }



    render() {
        const { propertyname, buildingtype, amenitiesdata, uiRoomType, amenitiesUiMap } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="jumbotron-fluid">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <NavBar />
                </div>
                <div className="container-fluid" style={{ paddingBottom: '40px', paddingTop: '60px' }}>

                    <div className="center">
                        <span style={{ fontSize: '18px' }}>Hotel</span>
                        <div className="form-inline" id="form" action="">
                            <button type="" id="propertyname">{propertyname}</button>
                            <select name="roomtype" id="roomType" placeholder="Room Type">
                                {buildingtype.map((roomtype, index) => (
                                    <option key={index} value={roomtype}>{uiRoomType[roomtype]}</option>
                                ))}
                            </select>
                            <Example />
                            <select name="adults" id="" placeholder="Adults">
                                <option value="1adult">1 adult</option>
                                <option value="2adults">2 adults</option>
                                <option value="3adults">3 adults</option>
                                <option value="4 adults">4 adults</option>
                            </select>
                            <button id="search" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            {amenitiesdata.map((amenities, index) => (
                                <div key={index} className="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                                    <p>{amenitiesUiMap[amenities].img + '' + amenitiesUiMap[amenities].name}</p>
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}


export default HomeNavBarwithSearch;

i want to show font amenities icon and name. but getting code like this UI

"<i className="fa fa-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>Airport Transfer"
```

Comment: Are you getting a string instead of icon?

Comment: yes i am getting like this <i className="fa fa-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>Airport Transfer

Comment: i have answered your question please check and accept/upvote it if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can either change your API to return the class name instead of the entire icon and use that or use "dangerouslySetInnerHtml" on a span, which will render the icon inside the span.

```
<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: amenitiesUiMap[amenities].img }} />;
```

I'd recommend the 1st approach.

Answer (score 0):

Instead having icon as string use as a jsx

```
 "AirConditioning": {
                    "img": <i className="fas fa-snowflake"></i>,
                    "name": "Air Conditioning"
                }
```

Like this it will work

Comment: i Tried your code. but still is not working instead of that it shows error. 
 ./src/Components/homenavbarwithsearch.js
  Line 30:  Parsing error: Expecting Unicode escape sequence \uXXXX "AirConditioning": {
                    "img": <i className=\"fas fa-snowflake\"></i>,
                    "name": "Air Conditioning"
                }

Comment: <i className="fas fa-snowflake"></i>  use like this sup remove those slash

Comment: @AshokKannan try this without slash I have edited my solution, it will work check once and accept/upvote

Comment: i tried without slash. even though is not working. Please checkout the below code . which are them i have tried eg 1:  <i className="fas fa-snowflake"></i>
                } eg 2:"<i className="fas fa-snowflake"></i>"
                } eg 3:"<i className=\"fas fa-snowflake\"></i>"
                }